# Is it possible to vary material colour depending upon thickness of the underlying mesh?

Tags: materials, shaders

Is there are way to create a material that will colour according to the thickness of the mesh it covers, based, perhaps, on length of edges at right angles to the mesh surface?

For example, white for a zero thickness plane, through a spectrum, to black at an arbitrary thickness beneath, that will change automatically if the mesh is manipulated.

Comment: And for [volumes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/89202/30849).

Comment: The second link seems like the one. I don't think it's about light path length, more about mesh thickness.