# Single Object transparency overlay with additive/brighter coloring

Tags: transparency

I have an object that bends over onto itself.  Its one color with some transparency.  See Image.  The left portion is like a string that has bent around in front of itself.

Right now, when the object overlays itself, it gets darker which makes sense.

But what I want is for it to get brighter.  I guess like an additive overlay?  Or maybe it would be subtractive?

I've tried a bunch of combinations of shaders (mainly emission/mix shaders) and I can't seem to make it lighter. I did get it somewhat working with a black background, but I have to have a white background.

Can I make the overlap region 'brighter'?

Edit:

I'm using blender 2.79.  Cycles Render Engine.

[image]

Edit

This is what I'm currently using in my nodes plus a bunch of other things I've tried that didn't work.  You can see at the bottom just a mix shader with transparency and glossy BSDF.  But none of the other things I tried there made it any better (all were worse, actually 1 was decent, but only if on a black bacground).

[image]

Comment: Answers will greatly depend on what render engine you are using, which you never mention. Please edit your question and add missing details

Comment: Updated, thanks! I should have mentioned I was using cycles.

Comment: Do you want the object to actually emit light? Can you also show us your current node setup, maybe a screenshot of what you tried? I don't think what you want to do is possible at least specifically as "blending modes" since [materials in cycles can't depend on the render solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/make-light-paths-only-pass-through-non-emitted-areas/86787#86787). Maybe it can be faked with a smart combination of shaders. Have a look at the *Add Shader* node instead of the *Mix Shader*

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos added my nodes. It can emit light. That would be okay. Right now it doesn't. But if it did emit light, that would not be a problem.  I tried messing with emission a few times, and couldn't figure anything out that worked.

Comment: It’s a double thick occlusion of the light. Not sure what you expect here. Violating the basic idea would most likely head into the uncanny.

Comment: I probably should have pointed out that simple alpha will work here. Use associated alpha, set your RGB to nonzero and your alpha to zero. Presto, emissive yet unoccluding solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to tune this simple material setup:

[image]

[image]

This example is based on the simple idea covered at this post:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/88356/13643

Comment: So, this works if the world background is black/dark.  But if you make the world background white (which I need), it does the exact opposite, and makes the overlap area darker.